# tickle() not called in PlaybackSupportFragment (leanback)

Tags: java, android, leanback

We are trying to make our Android TV app work with Android 9 (Pie). We're having some problems with tickle() in android.support.v17.leanback.app.PlaybackSupportFragment.

To test this we're using an emulator.

Scenario: Video is playing (using exoplayer) in fullscreen and we want to access the PlaybackControlsRow (leanback). This is done via the arrow buttons.

Action: arrow down button is pressed

Expected (Android 8 and lower): tickle() is called and PlaybackControlsRow becomes visible and accessible.

Actual (Android 9): tickle() is not called. Nothing happens. (Key stroke is registered in ViewGroup class but nothing gets to the fragment.) No error log entries have been detected.

BUT: If tab button is pressed (nothing happens) and then arrow down button is pressed THEN tickle() starts to be called for arrow key strokes until you leave that video.

What has happened in Pie to cause this? How do we fix this?

What we actually use is a subclass of PlaybackSupportFragment that we have created. In the subclass we call getView().requestFocus(); in the onResume() method. Removing this doesnt help.

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Stab in the dark, does your layout perhaps have the initial focus on the wrong view? Then tab is moving focus to the correct view, and button presses are received properly? As another commenter said, provide code please!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find a solution? After video starts playing, the playback controls auto hide. When you use the D-PAD to navigate, it's expected to show the playback controls again, which isn't happening.

Comment: I have same issue. Any solution for this  ?